# How to I pass a filters variable to useInfiniteQuery with pageParam?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to pass the queryKey variable alongside the pageParam in useInfiniteQuery? I've tried for a while but:

- Cannot get the page data
- In some cases, the data is rendered repeatedly.

How should I pass the variables?

```
export const fetchInfiniteVariants = async (
  filters = {},
  { pageParam = 0 }
) => {
  const records = await axios.get(baseURL, {
    headers: authHeader,
    params: {
      pageSize: 24,
      offset: pageParam,
      fields: [
        "name",
        "packshot",
        "packshot_size",
        "brand_logo",
        "price",
        "slug",
      ],
      // filterByFormula: `({validated} = 1)`,
      filterByFormula: `(${filterByFields(filters)})`,
      "sort[0][field]": "priority",
      "sort[0][direction]": "asc",
    },
  })
  return records
}

export const useInfiniteVariantsQuery = (
  initialRecords,
  offset,
  filters = { brand: "HAY" }
) => {
  const infiniteVariantsQuery = useInfiniteQuery(
    ["infiniteVariants", filters],
    () => fetchInfiniteVariants(filters),
    {
      initialStale: true,
      staleTime: 6000,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.data.offset,
    }
  )
  return {
    ...infiniteVariantsQuery,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *queryFn* you're passing to useInfiniteQuery has request context as a parameter to that callback, as documented on the [useInfiniteQuery page](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useInfiniteQuery):

> Receives a `QueryFunctionContext` object with the following variables:
>
> - `queryKey: EnsuredQueryKey`: the queryKey, guaranteed to be an Array
> - `pageParam: unknown | undefined`

You can destructure and retrieve your queryKey from that, as below:

```
export const useInfiniteVariantsQuery = (
  initialRecords,
  offset,
  filters = { brand: "HAY" }
) => {
  const infiniteVariantsQuery = useInfiniteQuery(
    ["infiniteVariants", filters],
    ({ queryKey, pageParam }) => fetchInfiniteVariants(queryKey[1], pageParam),
    {
      initialStale: true,
      staleTime: 6000,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.data.offset,
    }
  )
  return {
    ...infiniteVariantsQuery,
  }
}
```